# Batch files rename using filename list

Tags: bash, file, rename, batch-rename, filelist

I need to rename over 1500 *.jpg files.
I have text file with filenames list with 2 columns, tab separated:

- 1305 1979
- 1310 173
- 1311 172

Old filenames - new filenames

- 1305_1.jpg - 1979
- 1310_main_origin.jpg - 173
- 1311_2.jpg - 172

How i can check first 4 digits from first column and old filename and rename to another 4 digits from 2 column?

//sorry for my english

Comment: I don't understand: are files just `1305` or `1305_01.jpg`...? Meaning, would `mv col1 col2` make it?

Comment: my old file-names have different endings after 1305, 1310, 1311, etc.
i need to rename it to names from 2 column.

Comment: Is this a Windows or Unix environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop as shown below:

```
while read -r old new
do
    arr=( ${old}_*.jpg )
    if (( ${#arr[@]} == 1 ))
    then
        mv "${arr[0]}" "$new.jpg"
    else
        echo "Error: Multiple files found for $old: ${arr[@]}"
    fi    
done < file
```

Note that there is a safety check to ensure that you don't have multiple files with the same prefix. For example, if you have `1305_1.jpg` and `1305_2.jpg` you can't rename them both to `1979.jpg`, so the script will print an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, and remove echo after verify it's that you want. `changefile` is the name of the file that contains changes

```
while read from to; do
   echo "mv ${from}* $to"
done < changefile
```

You should reverse order changefile to ensure that 1306 is applied BEFORE than 130 and BEFORE than 13

Answer (score 1):

I already posted this answer for another question but this one seemed more relatable in terms of the question, the keywords and the complexity, I will added it here too.

You can use small linux app name krename, with javascript plugin turned on. It is a free tool with very powerful renaming capabilities.

1. Install Krename and open it
2. Add files
3. Go to plugins tab and add your javascript function to function definitions section, something like this:

   ```
   var files = [
       "Mickey",
       "Donald",
       "Duffy"
   ];

   function rename(){
     // krename_index is one of many special variables which can be added via ui
     return files[krename_index];
   }
   ```

This is a simple script that gets the job done, but it can be as complex as you like.

4. Go to filename tab and call your function in the template input as shown below:

   `[js; rename()]`

You can prefix the above code with `$` to keep the original file name and add to it. You can use "Functions" button to experiment further.

5. Preview new names and complete renaming by clicking Finish button.